# How can Levi be so fast when approaching the Beast Titan's nape in season 3 part 2?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In episode 17 of *Attack on Titan* season 3 part 2, when Levi takes out the Beast Titan's arm, eyes, and legs, Levi is in the air above the downed titan. When Levi goes for the kill, Zeke says that he doesn't have enough time to harden his nape. ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQJyCtELWaU))

[image]

Levi was in the air, reeling in towards the Beast Titan. The ODM wire was still taut but the ODM gear was set to reel speed. It's demonstrated time and time again that when people using the ODM would listen to the order from the captains/whoever was in charge, they all move at the same speed and don't seem to rehook. They just stay there.

We saw Annie/the Female Titan harden quick enough to be protected from Oluo which was really fast.

But back to Levi, there weren't any tall freestanding objects in sight, so how did he move so fast? Please don't say it was gravity. He wasn't falling, he was reeling.

Comment: I think he could be using more gas than usual similar how mikasa did in season 1 (?) which surprise other regiment on how she able to move so fast. If I remember it right, it was the episode where there is a cart stuck in the gate and the people can't evacuate because of it

Comment: well I don't think that was it for Mikasa she was in the city so she had a lot of things to grapple on to but ill rewatch it just to be sure. Thx for responding :)

Comment: And how would you use more gas? I think its the same thing as reeling. There is a limit to how much has is used.

Comment: After seeing this clip, it's somewhat similar to how he attacked Annie when they were in the forest. I could not recall this fast attack ever explained or elaborated in the anime and manga. What I do know is that Levi is skilled at using the ODM gear that there is probably some 'secret' or 'technique' to using it to enable someone to do this that only Levi knows. But this is purely speculation on my part.

Comment: yeah, I really don't see how Levi can do all that with the ODM gear. If it was realistic He would be like mich, good with the ODM but realistically, all of the things that Miche does when he stays behind the give the others time is doable. Unlike Levi and using his sonic attack on the Female and Beast titans.

Comment: Also, with Mikisa vs Female Titan in the forest, she was very good against her, but it was realistic. Everything that she did against her would work in real life. Unlike Levi but when he had her against the tree that was pretty realistic, I see no reason how tht wouldent work. But about this technique that Levi uses, how does he do it? Does he just hit shoot and reel out on the grips really fast? I should turn this into a question.

Comment: @W. Are hold up wait a minute. I'm not talking about attacking the beast titan im talking about how fast he is when going for the nape after disabling the eyes arm and legs.

Comment: Um, this is your question: 'How is Levi so fast when attacking the Beast Titan's nape...' You're basically asking how Levi used his ODM gear so fast unlike other scouts. And he is attacking the beast titan while doing this.

Comment: I was talking about approaching the nape not attacking.

Answer (score 4):

1. First: He's using more gas, as Mikasa did in S1E7.

[image]

But how can they use more gas? There is no valve as you can see in the pictures.

[image: How ODM Works 1] [image: How ODM Works 2]

<sup>Click the image to see the full size</sup>

I re-watched episodes 7 and 8 from season 1 multiple times but they said:

> No one knows how the ODM works except engineers

So I can only guess maybe they hold the "gas fire button" (as you can see in the second picture there are two buttons on the handle, the bottom button is for using gas) for a long time or maybe push it rapidly or push it with more power. I really don't know and I searched the whole of the internet and it seems no one knows.

2. Second: He's an Ackerman as explained on the [Fandom Wiki](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ackerman_clan):

> The Ackermans have an "awakened power" displayed by some members of the clan. Levi Ackerman describes it as "knowing exactly what needs to be done, and it lets the Ackermans exhibit physical abilities far above the average human. Eren Yeager learns from Zeke that this is because they were the result of the old Eldian Empire experimenting with the Subjects of Ymir. They can manifest the power of the Titans as humans, without becoming a Titan or inheriting any of the Nine Titans. When awakened, the Ackerman gains the battle experience from every single Ackerman before them via paths.

You also can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bPX8M8JKNw) at 3:40 for proof of the ability of the Ackerman clan or Ackerman family.

Comment: tbh they really dont explain everything you can do with the odm gear

Comment: i didnt know they could shoot backwards  or not retract or as u say increase gas pressure.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an increase in gas pressure?

Comment: @xpert [Link 1](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Omni-directional_mobility_gear_(Anime)) [Link 2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4975/48638) [Link 3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22091/48638)

Answer (score 0):

People here are thinking too much about "how Levi can use more gas than the rest of the people".

TL;DR: Anyone can go super fast like Levi, but most people do not have the ability to use and using it wrong would most probably kill the user.

*ANYONE* can use a lot of gas to move fast, Eren did this as well and almost died. Mikasa did that as well and almost died. THAT is the answer. You can for sure use a lot of gas, but do you have the skills to use it in an efficient way and know how much you can keep going before you get stuck without gas in the middle of titans?

Almost no one can reach this type of ability, and THAT IS FINE. Not everyone is a superhuman like Levi. Mikasa is the best one in her squad and became stuck without gas in the middle of the titans. Using a lot of gas is useful just if you can use it well enough to be worthy.

I can go further and I will cite this utilization in real life: one F1 Racer, maybe the best one yet, Ayrton Senna had one technique in his races, he made the turns using the thruster, brake, and clutch at the SAME TIME. Just like Levi, he burns a lot of gas and needs to refuel more often but he got a super advantage because his motor was with super high RPM at the end of the turn and because of that he got a huge edge against his rivals. Any other racers that try to use that technique that can't control the 3 pedals will burn more gas, can miss the turn, and even cause one accident. So for the other racers, is it really worth the risk? Mostly no, unless you are a genius.

And that's the reason. If you want to go even further, to use the DMT fully, you need not only incredible reflexes but also needs to fix the hook in ways that you can use your previous thrust to increment and keep going. If you go fast and your fixpoint is bad, you just burned a lot of gas to go faster and a lot more to go slower. It is one huge disadvantage in the *SNK* universe where gas is very limited.

So that's it. The bonus part is that if you go too fast, you can also hit something and die. And in *SNK*, it would definitively happen.